# How can I loop this function so that the animation repeats infinitely?

Tags: javascript, function, loops, settimeout, setinterval

I'm trying to adapt this function to loop infinitely, but the usual setInterval is not working.  I'd need the loop to start over completely, clearing the function I guess first?

```js
let ascii = document.querySelector('.ascii').textContent;
let asciiLetters = ascii.split('');
let displayLetters = document.querySelector("#text");

function animate() {
  asciiLetters.length > 0 ? displayLetters.innerHTML += asciiLetters.shift() : clearTimeout(moveType);
  let moveType = setTimeout(animate, 5);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ascii {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <pre class="ascii ascii-0">
    __     _ 
   / /_   (_)
  / __ \ / / 
 / / / // /  
/_/ /_//_/  
    </pre>
    <pre id="text"></pre>
  </div>
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution but I'm struggling to find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your code in a function, clear #text pre element after animate it, and setInterval every X seconds to call it again.

In this example i use 2 seconds delay:

```js
function start() {
  let displayLetters = document.querySelector("#text");
  let ascii = document.querySelector('.ascii').textContent;
  let asciiLetters = ascii.split('');
  function animate() {
    let moveType = setTimeout(animate, 5);
    asciiLetters.length > 0 ? displayLetters.innerHTML += asciiLetters.shift() : clearTimeout(moveType);
  };
  animate();
  document.querySelector("#text").innerHTML = ' ';
}
setInterval(start, 2000); // infinite loop with 2 seconds delay.
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ascii {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <pre class="ascii ascii-0">
    __     _ 
   / /_   (_)
  / __ \ / / 
 / / / // /  
/_/ /_//_/  
  </pre>
  <pre id="text"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: So simple, thank you!  I don't know how I missed that.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you want something like that?

```js
let ascii = document.querySelector('.ascii').textContent;
let asciiLetters = ascii.split('\n');
let displayLetters = document.querySelector("#text");

function animate() {
  let html = displayLetters.innerHTML;
  const line = asciiLetters.shift();
  asciiLetters.push(line);
  html = asciiLetters.slice(-5).join('\n');
  displayLetters.innerHTML = html;
  setTimeout(animate, 100);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.container {
  color: lime;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.ascii {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <pre class="ascii ascii-0">
    __     _ 
   / /_   (_)
  / __ \ / / 
 / / / // /  
/_/ /_//_/  





    </pre>
    <pre id="text"></pre>
  </div>
```

Comment: Actually - that's not quite what I'm trying to do.  I'm literally just trying to have the function loop.  So the ascii code types in line by line as I have it, then it goes to black, and does it again!  I know its simple its just passing me by...

Answer (score 0):

without setInterval function

[code in JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/nibaleyazi/3/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
    let ascii = document.querySelector('.ascii').textContent;
let asciiLetters = ascii.split('');
let displayLetters = document.querySelector("#text");
let asciiLettersLength = asciiLetters.length;

let i =0;

let animate = function(){


if(asciiLetters.length > 0){ 


displayLetters.innerHTML += asciiLetters[i];
i+=1;
//start over set counter to 0, clean the screen
if(i === asciiLettersLength){
  i=0;
  displayLetters.innerHTML = "";
}

} else {
  clearTimeout(moveType);
}


  let moveType = setTimeout(animate, 5);

};

animate();
```